# How to set exit code value for a command line utility in Swift?

Tags: swift

I can't find it in the language reference. The standard template doesn't give a clue:

```
import Foundation

println("Calculating")

// How to set and exit code when I done?
```

Answer (score 30):

Found it! You should just call:

```
exit(yourExitCode)
```

Note: there is no need at all to import "Darwin" or anything else. (For a decade now!)  Simply `exit(0)` is fine.

Comment: Requires "import Darwin" (or "import Foundation" which in turn imports Darwin)

Comment: For example `exit(000)`. There is a max code bounds - code `999` nor works.