# Seeking an "exit" equivalent in Swift

Tags: swift

I tried putting `exit(0)` in a small test (command-line) program. Xcode gave an error message stating `Use of unresolved identifier 'exit'`. This was confusing to me, since [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055924/how-to-set-exit-code-value-for-a-command-line-utility-in-swift) seemed to show `exit()` works. After combing through "The Swift Programming Language" I couldn't find any mention of an `exit` keyword/command. So how do you explicitly halt execution in Swift?

Comment: What is it that you want to halt? Is the app supposed to vanish from the screen?

Comment: In a command-line program you can use `exit(Int)`  In an application, you shouldn't cause it to terminate.

Comment: A lot of unhelpful nonsense from matt. Swift is touted as capable of writing operating systems. It's a general purpose language in design, regardless of Apple's plans for it, now or later.

Comment: Note that assert() still exists for exiting only during development (exit() will close your app even on distribution)

Comment: @SomeGuy It's a command-line application, when I say `exit` I mean it.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The `exit` function isn't a keyword or built-in in C or Objective-C either.  It's a library function.  In Swift, you can access it by importing `Darwin`:

```
import Darwin
exit(0)
```

Comment: I found `import Foundation` works as well.

Comment: Yes because Foundation imports Darwin already so if your importing Foundation you already have Darwin.

Comment: Doesn't work in swift 3.0.

Comment: @Makalele Try `abort()`

Comment: `abort()` is not a substitute. `exit()` is for normal termination, and allows you to provide a return code. `abort()` is for when something has gone wrong. It's basically forcing a crash.

Comment: `import Darwin` doesn't work on Linux.`import Foundation` does

Comment: You can use `import Glibc` on Linux if you want to avoid importing `Foundation`.

Comment: I guess these days, no need to import anything, right @robmayoff