# Swift 2.2 on Linux, "use of unresolved identifier 'exit'"

Tags: swift, swift2, glibc, foundation

I am attempting to exit a command line utility with error codes in Swift 2.2 on Linux. I have attempted the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055924/how-to-set-exit-code-value-for-a-command-line-utility-in-swift), but am still getting an unresolved identifier. A simple test script that replicates the issue:

```
$> cat exit_test.swift
import Foundation

guard 0 == 1 else { exit(0) }
```

I get the following error message:

```
$> swift exit_test.swift
exit_test.swift:3:21: error: use of unresolved identifier 'exit'
guard 0 == 1 else { exit(0) }
```

It appears that `exit` is no longer imported along with `Foundation`, but I'm unsure of where to look next for a way to exit giving a specific error code. I'm running `Swift 2.2-dev`:

```
$> swift --version
Swift version 2.2-dev (LLVM 46be9ff861, Clang 4deb154edc, Swift 778f82939c)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Comment: `exit` is an import from `Darwin` as part of the C standard library.  There is no Foundation equivalent.

Comment: On Apple platforms, Foundation transitively imports `Darwin`. On Linux, the (rough) equivalent to the `Darwin` module is `Glibc`, and Foundation may or may not import it for you.

Comment: This is on Linux. `import Darwin` raises "no such module 'Darwin'".

Comment: @rickster it doesn't appear to. `import Glibc` works like a charm!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`exit(3)` is basic Unix(like) API. On Apple platforms, such things are provided by the `Darwin` module, and since Cocoa heavily depends on those things, `import Foundation` automatically gets you `Darwin`, too.

On Linux, basic Unix(like) APIs are in the `Glibc` module, and `import Foundation` doesn't transitively import that for you. So, to get `exit(3)` and other such things, you'll need to `import Glibc` yourself.